# Infinitely many primes of the form $p = a + qb$?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Is there a *proved* result that establishes the status of the following.

> Are there infinitely many primes in the progression
>
> $a + qb$ where $(a,b) = 1$, not both odd, and $q$ ranges over all primes?

This is apparently stronger than Dirichlet's theorem.
I may well be very interested in special cases.

Thank you!

Comment: If $a,b$ are odd, then $q$ has to be even, so...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well spotted. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even in the two simplest cases this isn't known: note that the case $a=1, b=2$ is just asking whether there are infinitely many twin primes.  Similarly, the case $b=2, a=1$ asks for primes $p$ such that $2p+1$ is also prime; these are known as [*Sophie Germain*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophie_Germain_prime) primes and their infinitude is an open question.